# dcommit to sourceforge - how do I tweak my .git/config and authors file?

Tags: git, git-svn, dcommit

Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```
$ cat .git/config
[svn-remote "svn"]
        ignore-paths = ^(?:Releases|Projects|Scripts|Games|)/|^Programs/(?:Nif S\
canner|Nif Viewer|Raziel23x's Oblivion Toolset|Shader Disasm|Shader Editor)/
        url = svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code
        fetch = Programs/Wrye Bash:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
        branches = Branches/Wrye Bash/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
        tags = Tags/Wrye Bash/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
[svn]
        authorsfile = authors_with_emails.txt
```

Tried:

```
MrD@MRSD /c/dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/git_svn_WB (master)
$ git svn dcommit --username MYUSERNAME
Committing to svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code/Programs/Wrye%20Bash ...

ERROR from SVN:
Authorization failed: Authorization failed
W: 083f21d9aa799b62e325b5bb348f1ee82f9d7085 and refs/remotes/svn/trunk differ, u
sing rebase:
:040000 040000 f8e70f1f4670274788def25b32bd5d7246206b7b f05b3db6f8d2ea5ff54cd040
c4ef685cdd453233 M      Mopy
Current branch master is up to date.
ERROR: Not all changes have been committed into SVN, however the committed
ones (if any) seem to be successfully integrated into the working tree.
Please see the above messages for details.
```

As you see I am at master (where I just cherry picked one commit from a git branch - no fancy merging and stuff)

I have two questions:

- How do I tweak the url in the config - or what `<URL>` should I pass to `--commit-url <URL>` flag ? I don't want to mess anything up and end up committing in the wrong branch (as you see the svn layout is non standard)
- Actually I am committing another's changes. I edited the commit message to add:

  ```
  Subject

  Body

  Signed-off-by: AUTHOR <EMAIL> # added
  ```

  where `AUTHOR` matches the name in the SVN config but `EMAIL` does not. Is this enough for the author to be recorded properly ? I believe the email won't make a difference in the SVN side

I just want to be extra sure cause I don't want to mess up the SVN repo. I'd rather push over `https`.